# d3 directed graph edge

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I don't know how to draw directed esges with d3.js. I need to have rectangles of different height. like the image. I don't need these rects movable or forced layout. but I need a text on the top of edge that follows edge path which may be bezier . but I don't see any function in d3 takes two nodes and draws an edge between them.

[image]

Comment: Well, no, you have to create the SVG elements yourself. This tutorial might help to get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial.